# JQuery refresh data after Ajax POST

Tags: jquery

So.... I'm having a weird behavior when replacing data after AJAX POST success.

I have a table which contains products and after editing this products I replace the old data with the new one.

The weird thing is that if I edit 1 row works fine **BUT** if I edit for example: row 1 and after that I edit row 2, when AJAX POST success, replace the content of both rows with the new data. I can't find where is the error, still newbie on JQuery :P

**My table layout:**

```
                <tbody id="contenido_tabla">
                    {% for producto in productos %}
                        <tr id="{{producto.id}}">
                            <td><span class="codpro">{{producto.codigo}}</span></td>
                            <td><span class="pro">{{producto}}</span></td>
                            <td><span class="catpro">{{producto.categoriaID}}</span></td>
                            {% if producto.activo %}
                                <td><span class="actpro" style="color: green;"><i class="icofont icofont-emo-wink-smile"></i></span></td>
                            {% else %}
                                <td><span class="actpro" style="color: red;"><i class="icofont icofont-emo-worried"></i></span></td>
                            {% endif %}
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" data-url="{% url 'ver_medidas' producto.id %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verMedidaModal" class="btn btn-outline-primary menu-btn-medidas"><i class="icofont icofont-eye-alt"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" data-url="{% url 'ver_producto' producto.id %}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verProductoModal" title="Editar producto" class="btn btn-outline-success menu-btn-producto"><i class="icofont icofont-pen-alt-1"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar producto" class="btn btn-outline-danger menu-btn-eliminar-producto"><i class="icofont icofont-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
```

**JQuery**

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Al abrir modal:
        $('#verProductoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            //Si se realizan cambios en algun input dentro de la modal:
            $('#verProductoModal .form-control, .form-check-input').on('input change', function(){

                //Se habilita el boton 'Guardar cambios'
                $('#verProductoModal .guardar-cambios-producto').prop('disabled', false);
            });//Finaliza chequeo de input

            //Al hacer clic en 'Guardar cambios':
            $('#verProductoModal .guardar-cambios-producto').click(function(){
                //Obtiene los datos de los input
                var url = $(this).data('url');
                var producto = $(this).val();
                var codigo = $('#verProductoModal .inputCodigoProducto').val();
                var nombre = $('#verProductoModal .inputNombreProducto').val();
                var categoria = $('#verProductoModal .selectCategoriaProducto').val();
                var descripcion = $('#verProductoModal .inputDescripcionProducto').val();
                var activo = $('#verProductoModal .form-check-input').is(':checked');

                //Crea un objeto datos
                var datos = {
                    'producto': producto,
                    'codigo': codigo,
                    'nombre': nombre,
                    'categoria': categoria,
                    'descripcion': descripcion,
                    'activo': activo
                }
                //Envia los datos al servidor
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: {'datos': datos, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
                    success: function(contenido){
                        //Reemplaza valores de la tabla con nuevos valores.
                        $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.codpro').text(contenido['codigo']);
                        $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.pro').text(contenido['nombre']);
                        $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.catpro').text(contenido['categoria']);
                        //Muestra una alerta
                        swal("Producto modificado", "Los cambios se guardaron correctamente.", "success");
                    },
                    error: function(contenido){
                        //Muestra una alerta
                        swal("Error del sistema", "Si el problema persiste, contactá un administrador.", "error");
                    }
                })
            });//Finaliza clic 'Guardar cambios'.
        });//Finaliza modal

    });
</script>
```

[image: FIRST ROW EDITED.]

[image: SECOND ROW EDITED AND JQUERY REPLACES IN 1ST TOO]

[image: PAGE REFRESH AND SERVER LOADS CORRECT DATA.]

Comment: I don't think you provided enough code to really understand the problem. Need more context on your JQuery code. Is it being generated by the server?

Comment: What I do is send data from a modal to the server, and I replace the rows with the data that comes from the server in response.
The problem is when you edit more than 1 record without refreshing the page.. Every single row that has been edited takes the data from the response too.. It's modified on client side. because after refresh everything looks fine. I've added screenshots

Comment: Yes I understood the problem but you didnt provide enough jquery code to understand _how_ to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry.. I've updated the Jquery code with my full <script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace, `$('#{{producto.id}}').` to `$('#'+contenido['id'])`

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {'datos': datos, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
        success: function(contenido){
            //Reemplaza valores de la tabla con nuevos valores.
            $('#'+contenido['id']).find('.codpro').text(contenido['codigo']);
            $('#'+contenido['id']).find('.pro').text(contenido['nombre']);
            $('#'+contenido['id']).find('.catpro').text(contenido['categoria']);
            //Muestra una alerta
            swal("Producto modificado", "Los cambios se guardaron correctamente.", "success");
        },
        error: function(contenido){
            //Muestra una alerta
            swal("Error del sistema", "Si el problema persiste, contactá un administrador.", "error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {'datos': datos, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
                success: function(contenido){
                    //Reemplaza valores de la tabla con nuevos valores.
                    $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.codpro').text(contenido['codigo']);
                    $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.pro').text(contenido['nombre']);
                    $('#{{producto.id}}').find('.catpro').text(contenido['categoria']);
                    //Muestra una alerta
                    swal("Producto modificado", "Los cambios se guardaron correctamente.", "success");
                },
                error: function(contenido){
                    //Muestra una alerta
                    swal("Error del sistema", "Si el problema persiste, contactá un administrador.", "error");
                }
            })
```

the `$('#{{producto.id}}')` is static and always (I assume) refers to the first element so whenever you change a product it edits the first element

To remedy this you should change all `$('#{{productio.id}}')` with (I assume since I don't know spanish) `$('#'+codigo)`

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {'datos': datos, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
            success: function(contenido){
                //Reemplaza valores de la tabla con nuevos valores.
                $('#'+codigo).find('.codpro').text(contenido['codigo']);
                $('#'+codigo).find('.pro').text(contenido['nombre']);
                $('#'+codigo).find('.catpro').text(contenido['categoria']);
                //Muestra una alerta
                swal("Producto modificado", "Los cambios se guardaron correctamente.", "success");
            },
            error: function(contenido){
                //Muestra una alerta
                swal("Error del sistema", "Si el problema persiste, contactá un administrador.", "error");
            }
        })
```

Comment: if row 1 and row 2 has 22222 values both rows will updated